# Wrong result of JavaScript function (math operations)

Tags: javascript

Can someone please breakdown this script for me and tell me how the outcome is 30105? Thanks alot guys

```
function one(numOneIn) {

two(numOneIn * 3); //1x3

document.write (numOneIn); //3

}

function two(aNumberIn) { 

document.write (aNumberIn); //1

}

function three(numIn) {

one(numIn * 2); 

document.write (numIn);

}

three(5);
```

Comment: it's actually "30"+"10"+"5"

Comment: where do these numbers come from though i have no idea

Answer (score 2):

> three(5)

calls *three*, passing the number 5, then:

> one(numIn * 2);

calls *one*, passing 5 x 2 => 10, then:

> two(numOneIn * 3)

calls *two*, passing 10 x 3 => 30, then

*two* writes "30" as a string to the document.

Control returns to *one*, which writes the value passed to it (10) as a string.

Control returns to *three*, which writes the value passed to it (5) as a string.

So the final string is "30105".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reasonably formatted version of the code you've posted

```
1.  function one(numOneIn) {
2.      two(numOneIn * 3);
3.      document.write(numOneIn);
4.  }
5.  function two(aNumberIn) {
6.      document.write(aNumberIn);
7.  }
8.  function three(numIn) {
9.      one(numIn * 2);
10.     document.write(numIn);
11. }
12. three(5);
```

Let's look at how it executes.

The first few groups (1-4, 5-7, 8-10) are `function` definitions. They don't execute until called.

The first line that executes is `three(5)` (line 12).

It calls the `three` function on line `8` passing a value of `5` to the `numIn` parameter.

The next line that executes is `one(numIn * 2)` (line 9).

It calls the `one` function on line `1` passing a value of `10` (5 * 2) to the `numOneIn` parameter.

The next line that executes is `two(numOneIn * 3)` (line 2).

It calls the `two` function on line `5` passing a value of `30` (10 * 3) to the `aNumberIn` parameter.

The next line that executes is `document.write(aNumberIn)` (line 6), which adds `'30'` to the DOM as `aNumberIn` is cast to a string.

Line 7 ends the call to `two`.

The next line that executes is `document.write(numOneIn)` (line 3), which adds `'10'` to the DOM as `numOneIn` is cast to a string.

Line 4 ends the call to `one`.

The next line that executes is `document.write(numIn)` (line 10), which adds `'5'` to the DOM as `numIn` is cast to a string.

Line 11 ends the call to `three`.

The script has finished executing.

The final state of the DOM is a string of `'30105'`.

Answer (score 0):

`two()` writes 30

`one()` writes 10

`three()` writes 5

`document.write()` without any formatters will draw/write on the page right after the place where the cursor was last left.

If you add some formatting to `document.write()` you will understand what I mean.

Try to prefix or suffix `<br/>` to `document.write()`

EG: instead of `document.write (numOneIn);` rewrite it as `document.write ("<br/>"+numOneIn);`